# Как с помощью Playwright python, либо другого инструмента python (кроме Selenium) получить доступ к элементу

Tags: python, playwright

Как с помощью Playwright python, либо другого инструмента python (кроме Selenium) получить доступ к элементу **padding-top: 0px** и вывести на печать значение **0px**? (Значение padding-top изменяется при прокрутке страницы вниз, т.е. связано с пагинацией с отложенной подгрузкой )

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]?

Comment: Какие у вас возникли конкретные трудности при решении данной задачи?

Comment: Не знаю как подступиться. Нет знаний. Быть может подходящий инструмент какой посоветуете для решения этой задачи?

Comment: Получите знания, примените их. Если не получиться - вернитесь к первому шагу. Другого инструмента нет. Если застрянете, то задайте вопрос.